# Children's Fiction: Trilogy, pre 1975

Tags: story-identification, books

This was a series of books published prior to the mid-seventies:

- Trilogy;
- Full colour illustrations;
- Adult central character, not a child;
- Aliens schooled in water, but were, individually, very small; Possibly brought to Earth accidentally in some form of probe/research rocket.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Possibly a marketing tie-in with [Sea-Monkeys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea-Monkeys)?

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question includes plenty of detail that narrows the scope: a lower limit on time since publication, unusual features (colour illustrations; trilogy), details of main character, secondary characters, setting, and backstory.